# Best way for replacing fragments

Tags: android, performance, fragment

I'm interested in the best way to have a single Activity that switches between fragments.

For example, if I use Navigation Drawer presented here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, for each click on item in the Drawer's list is called:

```
/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
// Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
fragment.setArguments(args);

// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();

// Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

So every time (even if user goes to previously displayed fragment) a new fragment is created, and then it replaces the current one. Is there a better way? For example reusing fragment instances, or something like that?

Comment: You could keep global references to your fragments so they aren't garbage collected, and reuse them...

Comment: @Submersed is right. That would be the simplest solution. Pro tip: That a new `Fragment` is created each time is a good thing! It keeps memory requirements low and if there is some dynamic data from for example a database or web service in the `Fragment` than this data has to be retrieved again when creating a new `Fragment` resulting in the data being updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

you can make a public method in PlanetFragment that sets the position, and updates the UI.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    PlanetFragment planet = (PlanetFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

    if(planet != null) {
        planet.setPosition(position);
    }
}
```

However, your original solution should be fine. Fragment transactions are fast, and it is time to implement the logic that updates the UI. In most cases it is easier to recreate the whole Fragment, just like how you do it.

Consider this approach, if the Fragment needs long initialization that would result in progressbars and delays (in the UI). This way you can avoid the reinitalization, so it is possible to update the state only (the position in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If your list has few items and constant ones, you can have references to all of them and if the reference isn't `null` you don't have to make a new one.

That if your fragments are completely different from each other .. if you fragments use the same or similar layouts you can use just a single fragment and just refresh it's contents according to the selected index.